# X-server doesn't start properly: No window boundaries, close buttons, or unity sidebar

Tags: startup, installation, dependencies, re-installation

Good afternoon,

Earlier today I removed libjpeg (because I felt it needed to be reinstalled to fix this ghostscript related error). Unfortunately it removed a bunch of software along with libjpeg.

When I rebooted, I had nothing. So I went to tty2 and installed ubuntu-desktop. After reboot, X still doesn't start by default, I have to switch terminals and run it manually.

Unfortunately, it doesn't load the boundaries of the windows, alt-tab doesn't work, and the minimize/maximize/close options are unavailable.

How do I finish restoring my Ubuntu 11.10 x86_64 OS?

Thanks for all suggestions,

Alec Taylor

Answer (score 1):

Run the program

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

to test if your graphics supports compiz/unity.

If not, you should use the classic desktop: install the package `gnome-session-fallback` and at the login choose Gnome Classic (click on the gear near the username).

Comment: It was all working fine with Unity 3D before I ran `apt-get remove libjpeg`. So I'm sure my graphics support it.